# Font mapping Issue Oracle Forms 11

Tags: java, oracle, oracleforms

I have trouble with mapping my Fonts of my Forms. I followed [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html)

I added the following lines at the Registry.dat of the WLS server file:

```
default.fontMap.appFontnames=Courier New,Courier,courier,System,Terminal,Fixed,Fixedsys,Times,Times New Roman,MS Sans Serif,Arial,Wingdings
default.fontMap.javaFontnames=MonoSpaced,MonoSpaced,MonoSpaced,Dialog,MonoSpaced,Dialog,Dialog,Serif,Serif,SansSerif,SansSerif,Wingdings
```

and added the following line to the fontconfig.properties :

```
allfonts.wingdings=Wingdings
wingdings.plain.alphabetic=Wingdings
wingdings.bold.alphabetic=Wingdings
wingdings.italic.alphabetic=Wingdings
wingdings.bolditalic.alphabetic=Wingdings
```

There is absolutely no change, when running the form. It looks like the fontconfig is never read, because also mapping Wingdings to a Java standard font does work. I'm trying to map some Wingdings fonts. But mapping other fonts doesn't work either.

Anybody some ideas to fix this issue ? There is no workaround for the fonts, They have to be changed. There is no way to force a Font mapping.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar bug in Oracle Reports that Wingdings fonts did not appear when NLS_LANG is set to UTF8.

The solution was "The only Wingdings fonts available when using UTF8 are the characters between ASC 32 and 127. ASC 252 would display a blank because it is not supported by UTF8.

Any of the following font sets would provide a reasonable work around.

Webdings - chr(97)
Wingdings2 - chr(80)
Wingdings2 - chr(87)

Maybe try webdings and see if you get a better response. In the future you can find many forms solutions on my blog oracleformsinfo.com. Thanks Mia